# error in importing python custom logging module

Tags: python, logging

I am writing a custom logging module which can be imported into all my codes to create standard logs. Here is my logging module log_info.py:

```
class CustomLogger:
    def custom_logger(self, loglevel= logging.INFO):
        logger_name= inspect.stack()[1][3]
        logger= logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        logger.setLevel(loglevel)
        log_message_format= logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(name)s,:%(message)s')
        file_handler= logging.FileHandler('sla_data.log')
        file_handler.setFormatter(log_message_format)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        return logger
```

And here is my code where I am importing the above module:

```
from log_info import CustomLogger
#code to do a bunch of things
...
#calls the custom logging module as
logs= CustomLogger.custom_logger(loglevel= logging.INFO)
logs.info(f'logs: started_by: {windows_user}, started_at: {etl_start},\
     ended_at: {etl_end}, with no errors')
```

But I get this error:
TypeError: custom_logger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

Update: I removed 'self' from custom_logger() and it worked. I probably don't understand the usage of 'self' too well. I'd like to understand more and also how can this code be improved?

Comment: This resulted from calling the method on the class rather than on the object itself. If you want to Generally you'd create an instance of the class, then self would be passed in automatically. But there are many different ways to use objects in python; everything is an object. I would start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling object method via class reference right here

```
logs = CustomLogger.custom_logger(loglevel = logging.INFO)
```

Instead you either should use object reference, e.g.

```
logs = CustomLogger().custom_logger(loglevel = logging.INFO)
```

or you can make `custom_logger` a static method as there is no object/class reference

```
class CustomLogger:
    @staticmethod
    def custom_logger(loglevel = logging.INFO):
        ...
```

**P.S**

Take a minute formatting your spaces to satisfy PEP8 conventions